# Laplace's method in atypical setting

Tags: asymptotics, improper-integrals

I've been having some problems deriving large $ n $ asymptotics for the following integral:

$$
\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\exp(n\log(\Phi(ax)))\phi(x)dx,
$$
where $ a > 0 $ and $ \Phi $ is the cdf and $ \phi $ is the pdf of a standard normal random variable. The issue is that the maximum of the concave function $ \log(\Phi(ax)) $ occurs at $ x = \infty $, at which point its derivative and $ \phi $ are both zero. Thus, Laplace's method is not directly applicable. Are there any results that would apply in this situation?

Comment: Make the change of variable $u=\Phi(x)$ and only nice things will happen.

Comment: Thank you! I would actually like a slightly more general result, where $ \Phi(x) $ is replaced with $ \Phi(ax) $ for $ a > 0 $ (see my edited question). My guess is that this will involve some kind of asymptotic expansion (like Laplace's method would give), but I don't see how.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not a solution but a direction.

In this problem the general Laplace principle that the lead asymptotic terms flow from places where $\log \Phi(ax)$ is  maximized still holds, but the maximum is not attained at an interior calculus-type maximum but rather at the endpoint of the range of integration.

If $a=1$ the integral $I(n,a)=\int_{\mathbb R} \exp(n\log \Phi(ax) ) \phi(x)\,dx$ is, after the change of variable $u=\Phi(ax)$ the simpler integral $\int_0^1 u^n du = 1/(n+1)$.

If $a\ne 1$ the same change of variable $x=\Phi^{-1}(u)/a$ results in $$I(n,a)=\int_0^1 u^n \frac {\phi(x)}{a\phi(ax)}\,du=\int_0^1 u^n g(u,a) du,$$
where $g(\Phi(ax),a)=\phi(x)/(a\phi(ax))$.  There is an asymptotic  formula $1-\Phi(x)\sim \phi(x)(1+O(1/x^2))$  good for large $x$ that should allow you to work out the asymtotics of $g(u,a)$ close to $u=1$ and finish the job.
(Disclaimer: I have not worked through this myself.)

Comment: Excellent, thank you so much!